# How to do "in-place editing" of a JFace Table?

Tags: eclipse, jface, eclipse-databinding

In WPF (.net), when a `DataGrid` is made editable and set to an observable collection, there is a placeholder row. When one clicks on it, a new element is added to the backing collection and the table is put into edit mode.

Is something like this possible with JFace Table Viewers as well?

The only solution I can think of is to create a custom observable list that delegates to the "real" list I want to observe, but always adds an additional placeholder object to the end, which gets inserted into the "real" list as soon as it is edited. But that seems a bit hackish to me...